# How to write code for linkText for the html code

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I am new to selenium and trying to write linktext code for the html code

```
<a href="repopulateUser.jsp?authAuthSessionId=7DD74346650647B7BA9ED08C1ABAE66D&amp;roleId=bc95f1f2-9ccd-11e8-9a37-0050568817ef&amp;ROLE=Programmer&amp;ROLECODE=PROGRAMMER&amp;roleGrpId=f4c11ca7-9c1b-11e8-9a37-0050568817ef&amp;moduleId=cb475927-7eb1-11e8-97d0-0050568817ef&amp;studyId=null" class="labels">Programmer</a>
```

Code trial:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Programmer")).click();
```

the code above is not working, is something wrong?

Comment: <a href="repopulateUser.jsp?authAuthSessionId=52120EC3ADF1450B8040531490284CA3&amp;roleId=bc95f1f2-9ccd-11e8-9a37-0050568817ef&amp;ROLE=Programmer&amp;ROLECODE=PROGRAMMER&amp;roleGrpId=f4c11ca7-9c1b-11e8-9a37-0050568817ef&amp;moduleId=cb475927-7eb1-11e8-97d0-0050568817ef&amp;studyId=null" class="labels">Programmer</a>

Comment: The html code is mentioned in a comment.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it throw an error? If so, edit your question and post the error message.

Comment: It is not giving output.

Comment: What kind of output is expected?

Answer (score 0):

*linkText* should work if the element with the text **Programmer** is uniquely identified within the HTML. Still as the element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Programmer"))).click();
  ```

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.labels[href^='repopulateUser']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='labels' and starts-with(@href, 'repopulateUser')][text()='Programmer']"))).click();
  ```